# HIVEQL/HIVE Find the most common field in a column

Tags: sql, hive

```
    DATE      WindDirection
    1/1/2000  SW
    1/2/2000  SW
    1/3/2000  SW
    1/4/2000  NW
    1/5/2000  NW
```

Question below

```
 Every day is unqiue, and wind direction is not unique, SO now we are trying    to get the COUNT of the most COMMON wind direction
```

My query was

```
SELECT Wind_Direction,COUNT(Wind_Direction) FROM Weather
GROUP BY DISTINCT(Wind_Direction);
```

The logic is to find the DISTINCT WindDirections, there are like 7 AND then
group by WindDirection and apply count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group on count of occurrences of each direction while ordering by number of occurrences and limit 1 to get the one occurring on top

```
select w.wind_direction as most_common_wd
from (
       select wind_direction, count(*) as cnt
       from weather 
       group by wind_direction 
       order by cnt desc
     ) w
limit 1;
```

Comment: Parse Exception line 10:6 extraneous input '1' expecting EOF near <EOF>

Comment: I can't simulate but the problem might be a missing alias which I added. Give it another shot.

Comment: semanticexception ERROR 10128 not yet supported for UDAF 'count' Hmm maybe this is new

Comment: Aha. One might have to alias count(1) in order to order by it. Check.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to execute your logic using hive analytic functions:

```
with q1 as (select wind_direction, count(wind_direction) over (partiton by wind_direction) as total_counts from weather) select distinct wind_direction, total_counts from q1;
```